# Power BI - Calculate the amortized cost

Tags: azure, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a dax measure to calculate the amortized cost.

The amortized cost shows the cost of the reservations spread over the total period of the reservation.

I tried to check microsoft documentation that explains how can I calculate the amortized cost and it shows an example [How Azure calculates amortized costs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/reservations/view-amortized-costs#how-azure-calculates-amortized-costs)

The below screenshot shows the combination of azure plan & reservations

[image]

And the alternative is current approach where I have the actual cost, if a reservation is order on may 1, all the cost will be on that day and not spread over the total period:
[image]

I've a charge start date column and a charge end date column and I've a measure called reserved instances cost:

```
Reserved Instances Cost = 
VAR countsrows = COUNTROWS ( 'Fact Partner Center Costs' ) 

VAR measure_cost = 

CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Fact Partner Center Costs'[Total Amount] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'Fact Partner Center Costs'[Category] = "Reserved Instances" )
)

return
CALCULATE( 
measure_cost,
FILTER ( 'Fact Partner Center Costs',  countsrows > 0 ), KEEPFILTERS( 'Dim Azure Reserved Instances Contract'[Contract Client Id]<> BLANK () )
)
```

and after I tried to create this measure:

```
Reserved Instances Daily Amortized Cost = 
SUMX (
    'Fact Partner Center Costs',
    VAR ContextDate = MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
    VAR CostStartDate = CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Fact Partner Center Costs'[Charge Start] ), ALL ( 'Date' ) )
    VAR CostEndDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Fact Partner Center Costs'[Charge End Date] ), ALL ( 'Date' ) )
    VAR ReservedInstancesCost =
        CALCULATE (
            SUMX ( VALUES ( 'Date'[Day] ), [Reserved Instances Cost] ),
            ALL ( 'Date' )
        )

    RETURN

    IF (

        ContextDate >= CostStartDate && ContextDate <= CostEndDate,

        DIVIDE ( ReservedInstancesCost, COUNTROWS ( DATESBETWEEN ( 'Date'[Date], CostStartDate, CostEndDate ) ), 0 ),

        BLANK ()

    )

)
```

It showing the correct values but If I apply a filter to one of the slicers that I have, called Azure Reserved Instances Contract Key, it doesn't break down the values ​​by day, only for the 22nd

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very interesting because I'm trying to archive the same.

But first I think I need to clarify a thing, this is how you see the Reserved Instances and the Savings Plans:

[image]

You have to setup:

- **Pricing Model:** OnDemand, Reservation, SavingsPlan
- **Group by:** Pricing Model

This way you can see, for each day, how much you spent on RI and SP or On Demand.

The question I have for you now is: how are you pulling the data?

- Cost Management Export to CSV: in this case you should use the `PricingModel` column which tells which is which.
- [Azure Cost Management connector in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-azure-cost-management): in this case you have a dedicated table for that but I'm not an expert of that.